# GraphQL - POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, graphql

I keep getting the following error on my `graphql` queries and not sure why:

`POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?`

Am I doing something weird here? I have tried different recommendations with body-parser online, but still can't seem to fix it.

#### Server:

```
require('babel-polyfill')

const express = require('express')
const router = require('./middleware')
const expressStaticGzip = require('express-static-gzip')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.EXPRESS_PORT || 4000
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(/\/((?!graphql).)*/, bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(/\/((?!graphql).)*/, bodyParser.json())
app.use('/search/data', expressStaticGzip('public'))
app.use('/', router)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

#### Router

```
const router = express.Router()
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => {
    const { authorization = '' } = req.headers
    const universalFetch = (url, opts = {}) => {
      return fetch(url, {
        ...opts,
        headers: {
          ...opts.headers,
          authorization,
        },
      })
    }
    const request = createRpcClient(universalFetch)

    const methods = {}

    const catalog = Object.keys(methods).reduce((catalog, method) => {
      catalog[method] = params => request(methods[method], params)
      return catalog
    }, {})
    return { catalog, fetch: universalFetch }
  },
})

router.use(bodyParser.json())
router.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'application/graphql' }))
router.use('*', renderer)
server.applyMiddleware({ app: router })
```

Comment: @DanielRearden Thanks! That was it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`applyMiddleware` already adds `body-parser` for the GraphQL endpoint -- there's no need to apply it again and doing so may be causing your issue.

Additionally, I would expect `applyMiddleware` to be called before `router.use('*', renderer)` -- otherwise, I would think the wildcard route would be used for `/graphql` as well?

Answer (score 9):

In my particular case the client just missed "Content-type" header with 'application/json' value. After adding that the error message has dissapeared.

Comment: In curl, make sure to add `-H 'content-type: application/json'`

Answer (score 2):

I forgot the header **content-type: application/json**

Comment: This one solved my problem. +1

Answer (score 1):

This error also caused by **incorrect json** in the body or some other problems in the body, such as unnecessary wrong invisible chars. So check generated json for errors and what is actually presents in the request body.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also be raised because the body is too large.

I got it with apollo-server-micro inside a custom api route of NextJs.

It can be fixed by calling the `json` function coming from `micro` before apollo gets the request :

```
import { json } from 'micro'
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-micro'

const server = new ApolloServer({/*config*/})

const raiseBodyLimit: (handler: NextApiHandler) => NextApiHandler = (
  handler
) => async (req, res) => {
  if (req.headers['content-type'] !== 'application/json') {
    return handler(req, res)
  }
  
  await json(req, { limit: '1gb' }) // This is the trick to raise body limit
 
  return handler(req, res)
}

export default raiseBodyLimit(
    server.createHandler({
      path: '/api/graphql',
    })
)
```

I saw this in this [apollo-server's github issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/792#issuecomment-791843016).

Here are some information to build an [apollo server endpoint with next.js](https://apuyou.io/blog/serverless-graphql-apollo-server-nextjs)

Answer (score 0):

if your api upload anything you need to add the
{
uploads:true
}

in middleware while using graphql