# POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware in PYTHON

Tags: python, python-requests, body-parser

I am trying to send a request in python. I found the XHR, copied the curl and ran it in my terminal, worked amazing and I got a response. I then converted the curl into python code and get the same error and I have looked all over stackoverflow and google and all it shows me is examples of nodejs and nothing in regards to python. This is my code.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.trulia.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'cookie': 'tlftmusr=220127r6dy3udjlwtjr01eae5y1am065; s_fid=506AFCB7DCC3B70E-04D45F7B245F2989; zjs_anonymous_id=%22220127r6dy3udjlwtjr01eae5y1am065%22; _pxvid=634490ac-7faf-11ec-97bb-46596545526e; s_vi=[CS]v1|30F97FF6092382A7-400009A2368190B5[CE]; __gads=ID=0eb268a112aea6f0:T=1643315195:S=ALNI_MaLaqYG67wdCJeuAFsdIERsHIa4-g; commute=0|6|true; zg_anonymous_id=%22cc042b2d-29ef-4e76-b308-28aeaff9a2e1%22; g_state={"i_l":0}; stpa=91bdcbde35bfe55ff02e350d14f75e445b42ea3e41f2e46a203989d356bff928; stpr=cdcff13428427b5ddb1781c5d4859c89c6acef163f2b209d1646a1120a69b9a0; _pbjs_userid_consent_data=3524755945110770; _lr_env_src_ats=true; pbjs_identitylink=AhQek2Yd4okYD6kzV87whVYRVpd5gpbKXI814m-bhzxpNhZkGc6-cA7a7IWQn4fqY6mRjIPp7V1HixTEIYOnwEGtdpg2T68gnHO19Y1hvTvGTuMisyzrA_C177JiSpHmkBQ6; _csrfSecret=chVcTCGkojJf4aCkyL4Tb9W3; pxcts=70ff9020-11bf-11ed-801e-724c78677a6a; s_cc=true; branch_banner_closed=true; QSI_S_ZN_aVrRbuAaSuA7FBz=v:0:0; _lr_geo_location=GB; _pxhd=nuRoQ8PYpvv5IFHZqpNRyclkZmK2j5vYVdTClh/G2Lm2h8FzsW243Ht4FF3PyNSfdSDFcidjR6Cjanayd0MKGw==:DzVg679PRtFcVxHRZ9FRr8BJYXUOKB-zxP6g6iFwwgaaancqb/io9qDdHLhAfFJF9/6CNgdM1pddBEnzcOYqc1oKFtTbU2RuB3CWbZA8rC8=; _lr_sampling_rate=100; __gpi=UID=0000044f4a7ee8c2:T=1649400644:RT=1660020564:S=ALNI_MYBilKp0qq4hojdg9AyNF4Fhe1OnA; trul_visitTimer=1660019642110_1660021418934; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Mon+Aug+08+2022+22%3A03%3A39+GMT-0700+(Pacific+Daylight+Time)&version=5.8.0&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=1%3A1%2C0_234869%3A1%2C3%3A1%2C4%3A1%2C0_234866%3A1%2C0_234867%3A1%2C0_234868%3A1%2C0_240782%3A1%2C0_240783%3A1%2C0_240780%3A1%2C0_234871%3A1%2C0_240781%3A1%2C0_234872%3A1%2C0_234873%3A1%2C0_234874%3A1%2C0_234875%3A1%2C0_234876%3A1%2C0_234877%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false; zjs_user_id=%2259788808%22; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D',
    'origin': 'https://www.trulia.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/oh/bedford/59-john-st-bedford-oh-44146--1009668993',
    'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-bc-buildercommunitydata': '1',
    'x-contextual-highlights': '1',
    'x-csrf-token': 'OccCsutt-ZVwpowv1P9gB9RCaSrqkPZ02WJg',
    'x-papi-fall-back-disabled': '0',
    'x-pdc-api-enabled': '0',
    'x-rc-bls': '1',
    'x-request-id': 'client-92d6a7c4-68c0-40ed-89e8-a267d4269e50',
    'x-zg-search-enabled': '0',
}

url = 'https://www.trulia.com/graphql?opname=WEB_fetchAffordabilityQuery&transactionId=client-92d6a7c4-68c0-40ed-89e8-a267d4269e50'
params = (
    ('opname', 'WEB_fetchAffordabilityQuery'),
    ('transactionId', 'client-92d6a7c4-68c0-40ed-89e8-a267d4269e50'),
)

data = '${"operationName":"WEB_fetchAffordabilityQuery","variables":{"url":"/p/oh/bedford/59-john-st-bedford-oh-44146--1009668993"},"query":"query WEB_fetchAffordabilityQuery($url: String\\u0021) {\\\\n homeDetailsByUrl(url: $url) {\\\\n ... on HOME_Details {\\\\n ...HomeDetailsMortgageInfoAndHoaFeeFragment\\\\n location {\\\\n city\\\\n stateCode\\\\n zipCode\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n price {\\\\n ... on HOME_ValuationPrice {\\\\n price\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n ... on HOME_LastSoldPrice {\\\\n price\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n ... on HOME_SinglePrice {\\\\n price\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n metadata {\\\\n compositeId\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n}\\\\n\\\\nfragment HomeDetailsMortgageInfoFragment on HOME_MortgageInfo {\\\\n ctaUrls {\\\\n purchaseRates\\\\n postLead\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n mortgageInquiryCta(useRefinancePreQualifyLink: true) {\\\\n text\\\\n url\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n rates {\\\\n defaultRates {\\\\n taxRate\\\\n interestRate\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n taxRate\\\\n interestRates(creditScore: EXCELLENT) {\\\\n loanDuration\\\\n rate\\\\n creditScore\\\\n displayName\\\\n loanType\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n defaults {\\\\n homePrice {\\\\n price\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n loanDuration\\\\n downPaymentPercentage\\\\n insurance {\\\\n price\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n mortgageEstimateDisclaimer\\\\n __typename\\\\n}\\\\n\\\\nfragment HomeDetailsHoaFeeFragment on HOME_HoaFee {\\\\n period\\\\n amount {\\\\n price\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n}\\\\n\\\\nfragment HomeDetailsMortgageInfoAndHoaFeeFragment on HOME_Details {\\\\n ... on HOME_Property {\\\\n hoaFee {\\\\n ...HomeDetailsHoaFeeFragment\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n mortgageInfo {\\\\n ...HomeDetailsMortgageInfoFragment\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n ... on HOME_FloorPlan {\\\\n hoaFee {\\\\n ...HomeDetailsHoaFeeFragment\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n mortgageInfo {\\\\n ...HomeDetailsMortgageInfoFragment\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n ... on HOME_BuilderCommunity {\\\\n hoaFee {\\\\n ...HomeDetailsHoaFeeFragment\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n mortgageInfo {\\\\n ...HomeDetailsMortgageInfoFragment\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n}\\\\n"}'
response = requests.post('https://www.trulia.com/graphql', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)
# response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GraphQL - POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200152/graphql-post-body-missing-did-you-forget-use-body-parser-middleware)

Comment: My guess that there is something wrong with the server, not your python code

Comment: @KiraLT So unfortunately not.. I already have the apllication/json header. I have also verified that my json input is valid.